# Search string and select line in WPF listbox C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

in windows form application i do this to find string and select line

```
            listBoxGCode.SelectedItems.Clear();
            int index = listBoxGCode.FindString(N + e.Value.ToString());              
            if (index != -1)
            {
                listBoxGCode.SetSelected(index, true);

            }
```

in WPF i cannot get it to work, I've tried this

```
int index = listBoxGCode.Items.IndexOf((from ListBoxItem a in listBoxGCode.Items where a.Content.ToString() == "N100" select a).First());
```

when i run this code i get this message Window

unable to cast object of "system.string" to type "system.windows.controls.listboxitem"

do i need to add any code to the .xaml code?

Answer (score 0):

You might have directly added strings into the `Items` collections of the `ListBox`, so the type of each item in this expression is actually string, instead of `ListBoxItem`, this is why you get the `InvalidCastException`.

```
from ListBoxItem a in listBoxGCode.Items
```

To fix this, wrap each string into a `ListBoxItem` in XAML.

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBoxGCode">
    <ListBox.Items>
        <ListBoxItem>a</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>b</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>c</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox.Items>
</ListBox>
```

If you want to do this in code behind, you can do it like this

```
listBoxGCode.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem() { Content = "a" });
listBoxGCode.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem() { Content = "b" });
listBoxGCode.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem() { Content = "c" });
```

Comment: Thnx. i give it a try .